# Bounce once on a collision

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I have BoxCollider2D and EdgeCollider2D how can I make the BoxCollider2D bounce only from the EdgeCollider2D and only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tag to the Edge Collider game object, write a script to detect collision and check for this tag, then have 2 Boolean variables (e.g. played, collided) set to false at start, if collision with Edge Collider is detected and 'played' is false, set the 'collided' boolean to true.

In `Update()` check if the 'collided' boolean is true, if so then add a bounce and set it to false and set 'played' to true.

Add the script to Box Collider.

It would be something like this->

```
private bool played = false;
private bool collided = false;

void FixedUpdate(){
      if(collided){
          GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * FORCE MULTIPLIER);
          collided = false;
          played = true;
      }
   }

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
  if(col.CompareTag("EdgeCol") && !played){
     collided = true;
 }
 }
```